# Sum values in one column and add to another table

Tags: sum

My Table(BOB) is look like this:

```
Year       Month    Value
2010         1        100
2010         2        100
2010         3        100
2010         4        100
2010         5        100
```

I would like to add YTD values to another table (BOB2)

more exactly I want to see BOB 2 table like

```
Year       Month    Value
2010         1        100
2010         2        200
2010         3        300
2010         4        400
2010         5        500
```

Comment: Could you please toy with the formatting? It's difficult to see how your tables look and I don't want to edit it in case I get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I understand what you are trying to do.. but if not, please re-phrase your question... You can accomplish what you have asked by using the following SQL.

```
--INSERT INTO BOB2 (Year, ID, Value)
SELECT a.Year, a.ID, (SELECT SUM(b.Value)
               FROM   BOB b
               WHERE  b.ID <= a.ID) as RunningTotalValue
FROM   BOB a
ORDER  BY a.Value;
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7298/2/0) for you to look at.

**EDIT:** Change the ID column to "Month" after seeing the edit to your post.

Comment: It is bad practice to nest selects as a column in a sql query. Each time a row is selected from the database it has to do another query per row. You should rather make use of joins to avoid running into a performance nightmare.

Comment: @Ryan-Neal Mes...Thanks for the tip.. Will have to go re-look at some of the stored procs I wrote. Sigh

Answer (score 0):

See the answer below. I have simplified the query.

```
select 
   concat(cast(t1.year as char), cast(t1.month as char)) period_current,            
   sum(t1.amount) amount
from bob t1

   left join bob t2 on
     (t2.year + t2.month) <= (t1.year + t1.month)
group by
  (t1.year + t1.month);
```

What the query is doing is using t1 as the base table and joining on the period (year + month) then you want to sum the amounts prior to that including the current amount. I haven't added in all the edge cases, but this gives you something to start from. If you are restricting your query to a single year, this should be enough.